# notepad++ mark IP address with one click

Tags: windows, ip, notepad++

I am trying to find way how to mark with double click of mouse the whole IP address.

For example in case of an IP address 10.1.1.1. if I double click on it using mouse it only selects 10 or 1. I would like to change that so that by double clicking I can select whole IP Address in one go.

In default windows notepad it works well, but in notepad++ I not able to run it.

I’ll appreciate if some one can help me with this.
Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Settings` ->  `Preferences` dialog.

Go to the Delimiter tab

Set Open and Close to a space.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Double click on your IP.

Close the preferences window and now you can select IPs in notepad.